# Genric null condition check for any datatype in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to check for any null column present using below logic but I am not sure will this work for other datatype, Is there is any other generic way to check null condition in python which will work for all datatypes.

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df = sc.parallelize([ \
    Row(name='Alice', age=5, height=''), \
    Row(name='Kate', age=10, height=90), \
    Row(name='Brain', age=15, height=100)]).toDF()

df.createOrReplaceTempView("Test")
dfn1 = df.select([count(when(isnull(c), c)).alias(c) for c in df.columns])
df10=dfn1.selectExpr("stack(3,'name',bigint(name),'age',bigint(age),'height',bigint(height)) as (col_name,null_col_check)").show()

output : 

+--------+--------+
|col_name|null_col|
+--------+--------+
|    name|       0|
|     age|       0|
|  height|       1|
+--------+--------+
```

Comment: Yes it should work. are you facing any problem? Please note, it won't check the elements of the complex type for `null` but it will check if the column having complex type itself is null

Comment: Thankyou @SomeshwarKale : Actually I want to check null for complex data type as well, Since the datatype is not know to me exactly I am looking for any generic null condition which can be applied here for any data type.